# Can't Create Launch Configuration Due to Invalid IamInstanceProfile

Tags: boto3

Trying Create a Launch Configuration item, I get this error:

> Launch Config problem:  An error occurred (ValidationError) when
> calling the operation: Invalid
> IamInstanceProfile:AWS_EC2_INSTANCE_PROFILE_ROLE

executing this type of code w/boto 3:

```
self.as_client.create_launch_configuration(
                KeyName=f"{self.vpcid}-{self.profile_name}.pem",
                IamInstanceProfile=self.inst_prof_name,
                ImageId=self.ec2_inst.ami,
                InstanceType=self.ec2_inst.type,
                LaunchConfigurationName=self.ec2_inst.lc_name,
                SecurityGroups=[x.id for x in self.sec_groups.values()],
                UserData=userdata,
            )
```

I created 2 locally managed policies and attached them to a Role and assigned the role to an instance profile. (It seems boto3 does not allow  viewing locally managed policies in the Role,  only managed AWS ones,  except when explicitly trying):

```
print(iam_client.get_role_policy(RoleName="EC2AppRole",PolicyName="CloudWatchSendPolicy"))
print(iam_client.get_role_policy(RoleName="EC2AppRole",PolicyName="AwsSecretsPolicy"))
```

Here's the Role w/ policy details:

> == Role: EC2AppRole ==

> {'RoleName': 'EC2AppRole', 'PolicyName': 'CloudWatchSendPolicy', 'PolicyDocument': {'Version': '2012-10-17',
> 'Statement': [{'Action': ['autoscaling:Describe*', 'cloudwatch:*',
> 'logs:*', 'sns:*'], 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Resource': '*'}]},

> {'RoleName': 'EC2AppRole', 'PolicyName': 'AwsSecretsPolicy',
> 'PolicyDocument': {'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': {'Effect':
> 'Allow', 'Action': ['secretsmanager:Describe*', 'secretsmanager:Get*',
> 'secretsmanager:List*'], 'Resource': '*'}},

The Instance Profiles seems OK:

> == Instance Profile ==
> {'Path': '/', 'InstanceProfileName': 'AWS_EC2_INSTANCE_PROFILE_ROLE', 'InstanceProfileId':
> 'AIPAXQXBO3GJ2LGTKDJ3L', 'Arn':
> 'arn:aws:iam::516942649747:instance-profile/AWS_EC2_INSTANCE_PROFILE_ROLE',
> 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 24, 5, 30, 4,
> tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Roles': [{'Path': '/', 'RoleName': 'EC2AppRole',
> 'RoleId': 'AROAXQXBO3GJ2AUOHJMVV', 'Arn':
> 'arn:aws:iam::516942649747:role/EC2AppRole', 'CreateDate':
> datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 24, 5, 30, 4, tzinfo=tzutc()),
> 'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement':
> [{'Effect': 'Allow', 'Principal': {'Service': 'ec2.amazonaws.com'},
> 'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole'}]}}]}

Sorry I don't know how to properly format this post very well.

Any information I can share to help clarify?

I've tested everything in the  create_launch_configuration call to be correct as best I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use a waiter:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#waiters

or `time.sleep(x)`

to make sure the resource is available.

(Will wait to self accept) - Initial testing suggests it's a waiting issue.